# How to create multiple SQL logins, users and assign them to a role on a number of Databases?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am given a list of Active Directory users (domain\user1, domain\user2) and a list of Databases (DB1, DB2) on a SQL 2012 server where those users need to have read access. I would like to create a script that will do following for all AD user on each DB:

- Create a login
- Create a user and map it to login
- Add user to db_datareader role

I have put together following script which works for one user, but I would like it to work for multiple users as well. Is that possible?

```
EXEC sp_MSforeachdb '
IF ''?'' IN(''DB1'',''DB2'')
BEGIN
    USE [?];
    PRINT ''Processing '' + DB_NAME();

    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT name  FROM master.sys.server_principals WHERE name = "Domain\User1")
    BEGIN
        PRINT ''Create Login [Domain\User1]''
        CREATE LOGIN [Domain\User1] FROM WINDOWS WITH DEFAULT_DATABASE = [master];
    END

    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.database_principals WHERE name = "Domain\User1")
    BEGIN
        PRINT ''Create User [Domain\User1]''
        CREATE USER [Domain\User1] FROM LOGIN [Domain\User1]
    END

    EXEC sp_addrolemember ''db_datareader'', ''Domain\User1'';
END';
```

N.B. I know that AD group is another option, but this task is specific to AD users.

Comment: You'll basically have to generate that code and execute it for each user.  If it's a lot of users, you might want to open a cursor on the table which contains them.  Or you can generate one very long SQL statement.  Either way, you'll be using EXEC or sp_executesql to make more dynamic SQL.

Comment: You can query ad users with linked server here is the link make a cursor or from them https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2580/querying-active-directory-data-from-sql-server/